# How to use browsers File API with PhoneGap web app?

Tags: cordova, fileapi

I have created a PhoneGap based web app some time ago.

Since input type file is now possible on iOS 6, I want to use it and the native File API as well, but keep using PhoneGap to be able to put the app in the Appstore.

BTW: I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564533/how-to-disable-phonegap-apis-functionality), but this does not work: Everytime I access File functionality I get an ERROR from PhoneGap and it basically does nothing.

**Update:**

In fact getting the file (image) and sending it to the server works fine, but before that I want to resize the image (to reduce file size) by using [canvasResize](https://github.com/gokercebeci/canvasResize). When the function reader.readAsDataURL(file) is called, I get the following error:

```
-[CDVJKDictionary pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x208892b0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CDVJKDictionary pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x208892b0'
```

**Update 2:**

Here is the relevant code that I use:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileInput = document.getElementById('ideaCommitFileInput');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to deploy your PhoneGap application on both iOS and Android, I would suggest using a regular file input field for iOS 6 devices and `navigation.camera` for Android and earlier versions of iOS devices, assuming you are dealing with image uploads.

As long as your app has enough 'native functionality', I doubt Apple App review would mind that you used HTML5 File API.

Here is a good example of using the File API to retrieve a Base64 encoded image string: [Phonegap encode image base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286014/phonegap-encode-image-base64/14287866#14287866).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
In fact, that was the way I was trying to do. But the method reader.readAsDataURL(file) (with reader being a FileReader) creates the following error:
-[CDVJKDictionary pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x208892b0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CDVJKDictionary pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x208892b0'

I assume this error is due to the fact that my file object is one of a native HTML5 input, but the used FileReader expects a file object from PhoneGap. (See code above)